# How to solve a system of integral equations

Tags: equation-solving, integral-equations

I am trying to solve a system of equations as follows...

```
f1[t]/3 == (1/3)[Integrate[f3[t], t]]
f1[t]/(6/5) == Integrate[f2[t], t]
f3[t] == Integrate[f1[t], t]
```

I know the solutions are the following...

```
f1[t] = 3t^2 
f2[t] = 5t
f3[t] = t^3
```

How or which *Mathematica* function could be used to solve this? I tried `Solve` and `NSolve` and `NDSolve`, but they are not working. Any advice would greatly be appreciated. Here is a picture elaborating the problem. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Notice first of all that square brackets have a special meaning in *Mathematica* (they delimit function arguments), so you shouldn't use for anything else. In other words, the right hand side of your first equation should probably be `1/3 Integrate[f3[t], t]`. Perhaps you left off something else though, because I'm not sure that the first equation thus modified would be satisfied by your solutions.

Comment: But wouldn't that change the meaning of the equation? As in from (1/3)x to 1/(3x)?

Comment: Notice that `(1/3) (Integrate[...])` is equivalent to `1/3 Integrate[...]`, just like $(1/3)(x)$ is equivalent to $1/3\ x$, which is NOT the same as $1/(3\ x)$. I don't know which one you mean though. Do check the original form of the first equation to make sure nothing is missing, and only ever use `()` to indicate operation precedence.

Comment: Why not solve an equivalent set of differential equations instead? *Mathematica* doesn't have built in ways of solving integral equations. Something like `DSolve[{f1'[t] == f3[t],f2'[t] == 6/5 f2'[t],f3'[t] == f1[t]}, etc.]`

Comment: Oh ok. So, if I were to convert it into differential equations, would DSolve be the correct function?

Comment: Yes, but please check your original equations and your solutions. I'm pretty sure that your solutions don't match the equations, *even if* you replace the `f1` on the left-hand side of the second equation by `f2`, which is what I was assuming you meant.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the equations to account for this. However, I corrected the equations into differential equations, but am not getting an output. I will add a screenshot to the problem.

Comment: I've added the screenshot. The solutions listed are the same. However, the equations listed above are slightly altered. The final equations are those listed in the screenshot.

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {f1[t]/3    == (1/3) Integrate[f3[t], t],
       f1[t]/(6/5) == Integrate[f2[t], t],
       f3[t]       == Integrate[f1[t], t]};

DSolve[D[list, t], {f1, f2, f3}, t] /. C[_] -> 1 /. 
       HoldPattern@Function[a__, g_] :> Function[a, Evaluate@FullSimplify@g]

(* {{f1 -> Function[{t}, E^t], 
     f2 -> Function[{t}, (5 E^t)/6], 
     f3 -> Function[{t}, E^t]}}
 *)
```